# How to Handle the duplicate records and null value exception in Sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

So i have created a Table as

```
String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + FIELD_FNAME
            + " TEXT NOT NULL," + FIELD_LNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + FIELD_ROLLNO + " TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY" + ")";

    db.execSQL(createTable);
```

note: `FIELD_FNAME`, `FIELD_LNAME`, `FIELD_ROLLNO` are not null and `FIELD_ROLLNO` is Primary key also.

```
i m inserting values in this table from `EditTexts` on a clickEvent of a button,
```

before inserting i want to restict the user not to insert the duplicate rollNo in `FIELD_ROLLNO` because its primary key.

Also i want to make user attention with a dialog box if the user is inserting the null record in any field.

Im getting this exception on duplicate entry in `FIELD_ROLLNO` coloumn.

```
Error inserting lname=Hussain roll_no=08cs18 fname=Qadir
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
```

All i need is that How can i capture this exception and null value exception so i can show a dialog to user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [insertOrThrow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertOrThrow%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) and catch exception.

```
try
{
  returnedValue = db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, newEntry);
} 
catch (SQLException e)
{
  Log.e(DATABASE_NAME, e.toString());
}
```

Comment: can you plz provide me a link how to use this ant example except this docs refrence

Comment: Yes this is working some how but How can i make differnce that is user inserting the duplicate record or its inserting a null value to any column, as i have tested that in both cases its throwing "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed" exception

Answer (score 3):

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19:
>   constraint failed

So since `ROLLNO` is `PK`, there is implicitly added unique constraint that no two rows can have same `PK`. Primary keys must be always `UNIQUE`.

> before inserting i want to restict the user not to insert the
>   duplicate rollNo in FIELD_ROLLNO because its primary key.

So this can be solved in a few ways. You probably want to fix it on application layer and show some message to User if added duplicite / incorrect value. So my first idea is that you need to create method that will return all `ROLLNOs` from table(you should store them into some collection for example to `List`) and then before perform insert you start checking EditTexts data. At first you need to compare `ROLLNO` from EditText with `ROLLNOs` from db and according to result you show warning `Toast` or peform appropriate action.

> Also i want to make user attention with a dialog box if the user is
>   inserting the null record in any field.

You mentioned that you are using values from `EditText` so you can unsure this by "constrait" that

*"EditText cannot be empty but need to be filled up"*.

### Example:

```
public List<String> getRolls() {
   List<String> collection = new ArrayList<String>();
   String rollno = null;
   Cursor c = null;
   try {
      db = DbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
      String query = "select " + FIELD_ROLLNO + " from TableName";
      c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
      if (c != null) {
         if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
               rollno = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(FIELD_ROLLNO));
               collection.add(rollno);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
         }
      }
   }
   finally {
      if (c != null) {
         c.close();
      }
      if (db != null) {
         db.close();
      }
   }
}
```

And an usage in Activity:

```
List<String> collection = dbHelper.getRolls();
String rollnoBox = editText1.getText().toString();
if (!isDuplicate(collection, rollnoBox)) {
   if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(editText2.getText().toString()) {
      // make insertion
   }
   else {
      Toast.makeText(this, "This cannot be empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
else {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Your rollno already exists!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private boolean isDuplicate(List<String> col, String value) {
   boolean isDuplicate = false;   
   for (String s: col) {
      if (s.equals(value) {
         isDuplicate = true;
         break;
      }
   }
   return isDuplicate;
}
```

These snippets of code i wrote "just now" so also can be improved due to personal requirements. It should solve your problem. Check it out.

Comment: OMG..! this is so long way. i thought that i can do this by simply capturing the exceptions only. but thanks for this self explaintry answer.

Comment: @QadirHussain it only looks like long way..there is only one method and two conditions :) i just answer to your questions. I could write you an usage of catch but you should have db classes and ui classes separated from each other and approach wiith simple catch is by my mention "dry"